# OkHttp connectTimeout specifics

Tags: android, okhttp

I would like to know how exactly the connectTimeout in OkHttp works. The [documentation](https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-ok-http-client/-builder/connect-timeout/) I found is fairly unspecific: `The connect timeout is applied when connecting a TCP socket to the target host.`

Does that mean that establishing the TCP connection cannot take longer than this timeout? Or is it the way it is in [swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlrequest/1418229-timeoutinterval), where the timeouts behave like this: `If during a connection attempt the request remains idle for longer than the timeout interval, the request is considered to have timed out.` (so basically as long as progress is made, the total time to establish a connection is unlimited)

**Context in case you need it:**

We have replaced our Http Client implementation. Now we are getting some timeouts in the connection phase, where it worked fine before. I'm pretty sure the reason is a difference in behavior when applying the timeout values. The old Android code looked like this:

```
mOkHttpClient
            .newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(timeout.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(timeout.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(timeout.toLong(), TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()
```

In order to emulate the old behavior, I need to understand it first.